# Calling the result of a variable

Tags: python

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  It's saying total not defined, do I need to declare the variable outside?  It would defeat the purpose though, all help gratefully received.  Thanks

import random

```
def addition (a,b):
    total=a+b
    return total

a=random.randint(0,9)
b=random.randint(0,9)
answer=input("What is "+str(a)+" + "+str(b)+" ")
addition(a,b)
if answer==total:
    print("Good")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: You do not assign the result of `addition(a,b)` to anything.

Comment: `total = addition(a,b)` store return value from function.

Answer (score 1):

`total` is a local variable - it only exists within your `addition` function. The right way to use it is to assign the return value of the call to `addition()` to another variable, ie:

```
result = addition(a,b)
if answer == result:
    print("Good")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, it runs, but everytime i input the correct answer, it prints 'wrong'.  Perhaps my function is written out wrong

Comment: Your function is fine. But if you're using Python 3.x, the `input()` function returns a string, and a string doesn't compare equal to an int (hopefully...). You have to make an int of `answer` (and then you'll soon find out you'll also have to handle the case where the user doesn't enter a valid number <g>)